Test case not working when stubbing with Sinon
I am testing bar function, using Sinon to create stub for createFile. But when I run the npm test I get this error:
  1) index.js
       stub function
         should stub log:
     AssertionError: expected greet to have been called exactly once, but it was called 0 times
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/lib/index.test.js:26:31)
      at process.processImmediate (node:internal/timers:478:21)

index.js:
async function bar(fileName) {
  await createFile(fileName);
}

function createFile(fileName) {
  // public
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("done");
    }, 100);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  bar,
  createFile,
};

index.test.js:
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const expect = chai.expect;

chai.use(sinonChai);

const demo = require("./index.js");

describe("index.js", () => {
    context("stub function", () => {
        it("should stub createFile and callDB", async () => {
            // Stub createFile function in the scope where it's being imported (i.e., demo module)
            let stub = sinon.stub(demo, "createFile").resolves("create_stub");
            await demo.bar('test.txt');
            expect(stub).to.be.calledOnce;
            stub.restore();
        });
    });
});

package.json:
  "dependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.4.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "rewire": "^7.0.0",
    "sinon": "^17.0.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^3.7.0"
  }

CodeSandbox: Run npm test in terminal to run test.

bar does not call createFile via the exports object, so stubbing it there cannot make any difference. Also you shouldn't mock inside the module boundary (Jest here, but identical principles).

@jonrsharpe I posted answer to this question. can you tell me if there is any problem with this?

I solved this problem using rewire.
Step1: import module using rewire instead of require.
Step2: set stub using: demo.__set__("createFile", stub);

Code below:
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');
const rewire = require('rewire');
const expect = chai.expect;


chai.use(sinonChai); // mount

// use rewire instead of require
const demo = rewire("./index.js");

describe("index.js", () => {
    context("stub function", () => {
        it("should stub createFile and callDB", async () => {
            
            let stub = sinon.stub().resolves("create_stub");
            demo.__set__("createFile", stub);
            await demo.bar('test.txt');
            expect(stub).to.be.calledOnce;
           
        });
    });

});
